# Getting same type of Elastic Beanstalk EC2 logs without Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to host a web application. I found that I can get logs for my running EC2 instances through the Elastic Beanstalk console. These logs contain detailed information such as web/app server logs etc.

[image]

If I am not working with Elastic Beanstalk and I create the resources needed to run my web app without using Elastic Beanstalk, is it possible to get the same type of logs in the picture above? Logs which show web/app server logs. I tried clicking on the EC2 instace -> instance settings -> get system logs, although this does not return the detailed logs which I receive from the Elastic Beanstalk console, as you can see below.

Is it possible to get this type of EC2 logs, if I am not using beanstalk?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't, at least not out of the box. There is a special log collector script that runs on EB environments to grab those logs, which I don't think is open source or available on Github (unlike the EKS or ECS log collectors).